# Where in this animated pie timer should I add code to execute after the timer has finished?

Tags: javascript

I have created an animated pie timer using code from https://github.com/agrimsrud/svgPieTimer.js. I have changed the code a bit so that there is one circle that completes one loop and then stops.

When the timer has completed, I want to execute some code (e.g. reload the page), but I don't understand where in the code I need to insert this command. I have tried around a bit and found a place where it works (in the example below, I have added an alert-box), but I don't know if this is the best logical place to insert this code.

**Where should I insert it?** And why?

---

Working code sample (complete HTML page):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de-DE">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>1 Minute</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            svg {
                display: block;
                width: 250px;
                height: 250px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 20px;
                right: 20px;
                }
            #timer {
                fill: #bd4;
                }
            #border {
                fill: #9b2;
                }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <svg viewbox="0 0 250 250">
            <path id="timer" transform="translate(125,125)"/>
        </svg>
        <script>
            /* http://cdn.rawgit.com/darius/requestAnimationFrame/master/requestAnimationFrame.min.js */
            "use strict";if(!Date.now)Date.now=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};(function(){var n=["webkit","moz"];for(var e=0;e<n.length&&!window.requestAnimationFrame;++e){var i=n[e];window.requestAnimationFrame=window[i+"RequestAnimationFrame"];window.cancelAnimationFrame=window[i+"CancelAnimationFrame"]||window[i+"CancelRequestAnimationFrame"]}if(/iP(ad|hone|od).*OS 6/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)||!window.requestAnimationFrame||!window.cancelAnimationFrame){var a=0;window.requestAnimationFrame=function(n){var e=Date.now();var i=Math.max(a+16,e);return setTimeout(function(){n(a=i)},i-e)};window.cancelAnimationFrame=clearTimeout}})();

            /*! SVG Pie Timer 0.9.1 | Anders Grimsrud, grint.no | MIT License */
            /* https://github.com/agrimsrud/svgPieTimer.js */
            ;(function(w) {

                'use strict';

                // Date.now fix by Ari Fuchs, afuchs.tumblr.com/post/23550124774/date-now-in-ie8

                Date.now = Date.now || function() { return +new Date };

                // Draw SVG path

                function draw(element, rate) {
                    var count = element.length,
                        angle = 360 * rate;

                    angle %= 360;

                    var rad = (angle * Math.PI / 180), 
                        x = Math.sin(rad) * 125, 
                        y = Math.cos(rad) * - 125, 
                        mid = (angle > 180) ? 1 : 0, 
                        shape = 'M 0 0 v -125 A 125 125 1 ' 
                               + mid + ' 1 ' 
                               +  x  + ' ' 
                               +  y  + ' z';

                    // If array of elements, draw each one

                    if(element instanceof Array)
                        while(count--)
                            element[count].setAttribute('d', shape)
                    else
                        element.setAttribute('d', shape)
                }

                // Prepare timer
                // Define in global scope

                w.svgPieTimer = function(props) {

                    var element = props.element,
                        duration = props.duration || 1000;

                    // Optional warning

                    if(!element) throw "SVG Pie Timer: Error - element required"

                    // This part might be confusing:
                    // If n==0, do infinite loops
                    // In other cases where n is set, do n loops
                    // If n is not set, do 1 loop
                    // Do it this way to prevent mixing n==0 and !n

                    var end = Date.now() + duration;

                    // Animate frame by frame

                    (function frame() {
                        var current = Date.now(),
                            remaining = end - current,

                            // Now set rotation rate
                            // E.g. 50% of first loop returns 1.5
                            // E.g. 75% of sixth loop returns 6.75
                            // Has to return >0 for SVG to be drawn correctly
                            // If you need the current loop, use Math.floor(rate)

                            rate = 1 - remaining / duration;

                        // As requestAnimationFrame will draw whenever capable, 
                        // the animation might end before it reaches 100%.
                        // Let's simulate completeness on the last visual
                        // frame of the loop, regardless of actual progress

                        if(remaining < 60) {

                            // 1.0 might break, set to slightly lower than 1
                            // Update: Set to slightly lower than n instead

                            draw(element, 1 - 0.0001);

                            // Stop animating when the circle is full
    alert("Done!");
                            if(remaining < duration) {
                                return
                            }
                        }

                        // Draw

                        draw(element, rate);

                        // Request next frame

                       requestAnimationFrame(frame);
                    }());
                }

            })(window, undefined);

            svgPieTimer({
                // Element (Required) SVG sub element to animate. Accepts array.
                element: [timer],

                // Duration (Optional) In milliseconds. Defaults to 1000.
                duration: 3000
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

as i understand, you should add code instead of alert, right here

```
// Stop animating when the circle is full
    alert("Done!");
```

for example window.location.reload() to reload page

Because here we got condition

```
if(remaining < 60) {
    // code to execute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I purpose something like this. 
In this version you can pass any function to timer you want to be executed after the timer ends.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de-DE">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>1 Minute</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            svg {
                display: block;
                width: 250px;
                height: 250px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 20px;
                right: 20px;
                }
            #timer {
                fill: #bd4;
                }
            #border {
                fill: #9b2;
                }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <svg viewbox="0 0 250 250">
            <path id="timer" transform="translate(125,125)"/>
        </svg>
        <script>
            /* http://cdn.rawgit.com/darius/requestAnimationFrame/master/requestAnimationFrame.min.js */
            "use strict";if(!Date.now)Date.now=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};(function(){var n=["webkit","moz"];for(var e=0;e<n.length&&!window.requestAnimationFrame;++e){var i=n[e];window.requestAnimationFrame=window[i+"RequestAnimationFrame"];window.cancelAnimationFrame=window[i+"CancelAnimationFrame"]||window[i+"CancelRequestAnimationFrame"]}if(/iP(ad|hone|od).*OS 6/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)||!window.requestAnimationFrame||!window.cancelAnimationFrame){var a=0;window.requestAnimationFrame=function(n){var e=Date.now();var i=Math.max(a+16,e);return setTimeout(function(){n(a=i)},i-e)};window.cancelAnimationFrame=clearTimeout}})();

            /*! SVG Pie Timer 0.9.1 | Anders Grimsrud, grint.no | MIT License */
            /* https://github.com/agrimsrud/svgPieTimer.js */
            ;(function(w) {

                'use strict';

                // Date.now fix by Ari Fuchs, afuchs.tumblr.com/post/23550124774/date-now-in-ie8

                Date.now = Date.now || function() { return +new Date };

                // Draw SVG path

                function draw(element, rate) {
                    var count = element.length,
                        angle = 360 * rate;

                    angle %= 360;

                    var rad = (angle * Math.PI / 180), 
                        x = Math.sin(rad) * 125, 
                        y = Math.cos(rad) * - 125, 
                        mid = (angle > 180) ? 1 : 0, 
                        shape = 'M 0 0 v -125 A 125 125 1 ' 
                               + mid + ' 1 ' 
                               +  x  + ' ' 
                               +  y  + ' z';

                    // If array of elements, draw each one

                    if(element instanceof Array)
                        while(count--)
                            element[count].setAttribute('d', shape)
                    else
                        element.setAttribute('d', shape)
                }

                // Prepare timer
                // Define in global scope

                w.svgPieTimer = function(props) {

                    var element = props.element,
                        duration = props.duration || 1000,
                        callback = props.callback || function(){};

                    // Optional warning

                    if(!element) throw "SVG Pie Timer: Error - element required"

                    // This part might be confusing:
                    // If n==0, do infinite loops
                    // In other cases where n is set, do n loops
                    // If n is not set, do 1 loop
                    // Do it this way to prevent mixing n==0 and !n

                    var end = Date.now() + duration;

                    // Animate frame by frame

                    (function frame() {
                        var current = Date.now(),
                            remaining = end - current,

                            // Now set rotation rate
                            // E.g. 50% of first loop returns 1.5
                            // E.g. 75% of sixth loop returns 6.75
                            // Has to return >0 for SVG to be drawn correctly
                            // If you need the current loop, use Math.floor(rate)

                            rate = 1 - remaining / duration;

                        // As requestAnimationFrame will draw whenever capable, 
                        // the animation might end before it reaches 100%.
                        // Let's simulate completeness on the last visual
                        // frame of the loop, regardless of actual progress

                        if(remaining < 60) {

                            // 1.0 might break, set to slightly lower than 1
                            // Update: Set to slightly lower than n instead

                            draw(element, 1 - 0.0001);

                            // Stop animating when the circle is full
    
                            if(remaining <= 0) {
                                setTimeout(callback,0);
                                return
                            }
                        }

                        // Draw

                        draw(element, rate);

                        // Request next frame

                       requestAnimationFrame(frame);
                    }());
                }

            })(window, undefined);

            svgPieTimer({
                // Element (Required) SVG sub element to animate. Accepts array.
                element: [timer],

                // Duration (Optional) In milliseconds. Defaults to 1000.
                duration: 3000,
                callback:function() { alert("Timer is gone!"); }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Nice. But why inside and not outside of `if(remaining < duration) {` ?

Comment: I made some editing. I think this condition is wrong `if (remaining < duration)`. Correct condition probably is `if (remaining<=0)`